# Find matching rows between two dataframes by just the first word

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, tidyr

I have two datasets that contain an University column as follows

```
University | Expenditures

Abilene Christian University | 7041
Adelphi University | 10527
Albertson College | 9727
Boston University | 1234
etc.
```

```
University | Power_Rating
Abilene Christian | 0.5064
Air Force | 0.6543
Alabama | 0.7391
Boston | 0.324
etc.
```

I am trying to combine both dataframes to create a overall dataframe that consists of the University, Power_Rating, and Expenditures columns all together.

The final dataframe would for example have Abilene Christian University and Boston but would not include any rows that do not match to each other.

```
# Loading necessary libraries
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")

# Reading and setting the relevant datasets
college_basketball_df <- read.csv("cbb19.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
us_colleges_df <- read.csv("College.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Selecting relevant columns in the dataframes ()
us_colleges_df <- us_colleges_df %>% 
  select(X, Expend) %>% 
  rename(University = X, Expenditures = Expend)

college_basketball_df <- college_basketball_df %>% 
  select(TEAM, BARTHAG) %>% 
  rename(University = TEAM, Power_Rating = BARTHAG)

# Arrange both datasets so that they be combined/joined together
us_colleges_df <- arrange(us_colleges_df, University)
college_basketball_df <- arrange(college_basketball_df, University)

View(us_colleges_df)
View(college_basketball_df)
combined_df <- left_join(us_colleges_df, college_basketball_df, by="University")
```

My current code uses left_join which tries to find exact matches in rows between dataframes (this results in the entire power_rating column to be NA since there are no matching rows) and I would like to know if there is a way to join by just the first word in the University column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably extract one word  from `University` column and then do a join.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% mutate(name = stringr::word(University)) %>%
   left_join(df2 %>% mutate(name = stringr::word(University)), by = "name")
```

Comment: For future reference, how can I extract more than one word from the rows in the University column? For ex: there are multiple universities that start with the word "North" which makes it look like my final dataframe contains duplicate data.

Comment: You can use some regex to get first two words : `df1 %>%
  mutate(name = sub("(\\w+\\s+\\w+).*", "\\1", University))`, do the same with `df2`.

Comment: One last question, do I change the 1 in "\\1" to increase the number of words to extract?

Comment: No..you need to change the regex or split the string into words and select first `n` words Or `sapply(strsplit(df1$University, " "), head, 2)`